# External css or javascript file is not accessible

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently i am working with `libwebsockets`.
https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/fix_readme_format/README.test-apps.md.

I have build and installed in home directory. I ran the test server using `README.test-apps.md` readme The websocket is created but server don't acess the css or javascript file in html code(test.html).

I google but most of places says that change the permission to 755 to server directory but it din't help me .

My pc is Ubuntu 14.04 .

**Here is the snapshot.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal you should type

```
sudo chmod 755 /path/to/css or javascript file/
```

Comment: thanks dude, i changed permission of css file but still the same problem.